# Redux updating object in an array (React-Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

Trying to learn Redux. I am building a list app. From the home screen you can see all your lists and click on one to update. You can also create a new list.

So I've made a check to see if you navigate to the list component with data, the action upon 'save' will be UPDATE_LIST. If you navigate to the list component with no data, the action upon 'save' will be NEW_LIST. The new list works but the update does not. If you need to see more files, let me know. Thank you.

This is the list component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { newList, updateList } from '../store/tagActions';


class List extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            title: '',
            tags: [],
            mentions: [],

            tagValue: '',
            mentionValue: '',

            id: null
        }
    }

    submitTag = (text) => {
        this.setState({ 
            tags: [
                ...this.state.tags, 
                text
            ],
            tagValue: ''
        })
    }

    submitMention = (text) => {
        this.setState({
            mentions: [
                ...this.state.mentions,
                text
            ],
            mentionValue: ''
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.route.params.data !== null) {
            const { title, tags, mentions, id } = this.props.route.params
            this.setState({ 
                id: id,
                title: title,
                tags: tags,
                mentions: mentions
            })
        } else return
    }

    save = () => {
        if (this.props.route.params.data !== null) {
            this.props.updateList(
                id = this.state.id,
                title = this.state.title,
                tags = this.state.tags,
                mentions = this.state.mentions
            )
        } else {
            this.props.newList(
                title = this.state.title, 
                tags = this.state.tags,
                mentions = this.state.mentions
            )
        }
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <TextInput //==================================== TITLE
                    value={this.state.title}
                    style={styles.title}
                    placeholder='add Title..'
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState( {title: text} ) }
                />

                <View style={styles.allTags}>
                    <Text>{this.state.id}</Text>

                    <View style={styles.tagsList}>
                        {
                            this.state.tags.map((tag => (
                                <Text key={tag} style={styles.tags}>#{tag}</Text>
                            )))
                        }
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.mentionsList}>
                        {
                            this.state.mentions.map((mention => (
                                <Text key={mention} style={styles.mentions}>@{mention}</Text>
                            )))
                        }
                    </View>

                </View>

                <TextInput // =================================== TAGS
                    value={ this.state.tagValue }
                    style={styles.tagsInput}
                    placeholder='add #Tags..'
                    placeholderTextColor = "#efefef"
                    autoCorrect = { false }
                    autoCapitalize = 'none'
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState( {tagValue: text}) }
                    onSubmitEditing={() => this.submitTag(this.state.tagValue)}
                />

                <TextInput //===================================== MENTIONS
                    value={ this.state.mentionValue }
                    style={styles.mentionsInput}
                    placeholder='add @Mentions..' 
                    placeholderTextColor = "#efefef"
                    autoCorrect = { false }
                    autoCapitalize = 'none'
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState( {mentionValue: text})}
                    onSubmitEditing= {() => this.submitMention(this.state.mentionValue)}
                />  

                <Button
                    title='save'
                    onPress={() => {
                            this.save();
                        }
                    }
                />


            </View>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return { state }
  };



export default connect(mapStateToProps, { newList, updateList }) (List);
```

tagActions.js

```
let nextId = 0;

export const newList = (title, tags, mentions) => (
    {
        type: 'NEW_LIST',
        payload: {
            id: ++nextId,
            title: title,
            tags: tags,
            mentions: mentions
        }
    }
);

export const updateList = (title, tags, mentions, id) => (
    {
        type: 'UPDATE_LIST',
        payload: {
            id: id,
            title: title,
            tags: tags,
            mentions: mentions
        }
    }
);
```

tagReducer.js:

```
const tagReducer = (state = [], action) => {

    switch (action.type) {

        case 'NEW_LIST':
             //add tags and mentions later
            const { id, title, tags, mentions } = action.payload;
            return [
                ...state,
                {
                    id: id,
                    title: title,
                    tags: tags,
                    mentions: mentions
                }
            ]
        case 'UPDATE_LIST':

            return state.map((item, index) => {
                if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
                    return { 
                        ...item,
                        title: action.payload.title,
                        tags: action.payload.tags,
                        mentions: action.payload.mentions
                    }
                } else { return item }

            })

        default: 
            return state;
    }
};


export default tagReducer;
```

Comment: Can you add `updateList` and reducer code?

Comment: Just added both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By sending args like so

---

```
export const updateList = (title, tags, mentions, id) => (
```

---

In the scope of the function, the first arg that the function will be called with gonna be `title`, and even by doing something like this

---

```
  this.props.updateList(
            id = this.state.id,
            title = this.state.title,
            tags = this.state.tags,
            mentions = this.state.mentions
        )
```

---

what you sent as `this.state.id`, gonna be evaluate as `title`. (not python alert)

so you have two options, either organize args as in function, or send object with keys

---

```
  this.props.updateList({
            id: this.state.id,
            title: this.state.title,
            tags: this.state.tags,
            mentions: this.state.mentions
        })

  export const updateList = ({title, tags, mentions, id}) => (
```

---

Anyhow, of course you can use array as data structure for state, sorry I mislead you

---

```
     const tagReducer = (state = [], action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
       const { id, title, tags, mentions } = action.payload || {};
       case 'NEW_LIST':
         //add tags and mentions later
        return [ ...state, { id, title, tags, mentions } ]

       case 'UPDATE_LIST':
        return state.map(item => 
             item.id === id ? { ...item, title, tags, mentions} : item 
            )

       default: return state;
     }
   };


   export default tagReducer;
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Would setting state to an object solve my problem or is that just helpful to do?

Comment: Is it just more helpful and clean, please update if problem still exist...

Comment: form your question now I understand two things, first that I had a mistake and state suppose to be array, and second that you are used to python and therefore found your bug. editing my answer now, hope this time anything will work

Comment: Ah that is totally it. I knew it was something silly like that. Thank you so much.

Comment: you welcome :) added also a correction to the reducer for being an array, and totally get it I'm new in python and suffer for syntax habits :/